# XFCE windows drawing buggy

Tags: updates, graphics, xfce

I just upgraded to raring, and accidentally installed proposed updates.

Now Chrome and Sublime Text are not drawn correctly.

Here is my sources.list

```
#############################################################
################### OFFICIAL UBUNTU REPOS ###################
#############################################################

###### Ubuntu Main Repos
deb http://sa.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted universe multiverse 

###### Ubuntu Update Repos
deb http://sa.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-security main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://sa.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates main restricted universe multiverse 
#deb http://sa.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-proposed main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://sa.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-backports main restricted universe multiverse 

###### Ubuntu Partner Repo
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu raring partner

###### Ubuntu Extras Repo
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring main

##############################################################
##################### UNOFFICIAL  REPOS ######################
##############################################################

###### 3rd Party Binary Repos

#### Banshee - https://edge.launchpad.net/~banshee-team
## Run this command: sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 6E80C6B7
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/banshee-team/ppa/ubuntu raring main

#### Dropbox - http://dropbox.com
## Run this command: sudo apt-key adv --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys 5044912E
deb http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu/ raring main

#### GetDeb - http://www.getdeb.net
## Run this command: wget -q -O- http://archive.getdeb.net/getdeb-archive.key | sudo apt-key add -
deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu raring-getdeb apps

#### Gimp PPA - https://launchpad.net/~otto-kesselgulasch/+archive/gimp
## Run this command: sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 614C4B38
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/otto-kesselgulasch/gimp/ubuntu raring main

#### Google Chrome Browser - http://www.google.com/linuxrepositories/
## Run this command: wget -q https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub -O- | sudo apt-key add -
deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main

#### Google Earth - http://www.google.com/linuxrepositories/
## Run this command: wget -q https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub -O- | sudo apt-key add -
deb http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb/ stable main

#### JDownloader PPA - https://launchpad.net/~jd-team
## Run this command: sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 6A68F637
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/jd-team/jdownloader/ubuntu raring main

#### LibreOffice - http://www.documentfoundation.org/download/
## Run this command: sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 1378B444
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu raring main

#### Medibuntu - http://www.medibuntu.org/ 
## Run this command: sudo apt-get --quiet update && sudo apt-get --yes --quiet --allow-unauthenticated install medibuntu-keyring && sudo apt-get --quiet update
deb http://packages.medibuntu.org/ raring free non-free 

#### Oracle Java (JDK) Installer PPA - http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html
## Run this command: sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys EEA14886
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu raring main

#### Ubuntu Tweak PPA - http://ubuntu-tweak.com/
## Run this command: sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 0624A220
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ubuntu raring main

#### UNetbootin - http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/
## Run this command: sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys FC91AE7E
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/ppa/ubuntu raring main

#### X Updates - https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates/
## Run this command: sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys AF1CDFA9
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates/ubuntu raring main
```

Edit :

```
$ sudo lspci -v | grep -A10 VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GSE Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8340
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at f7f00000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512K]
    I/O ports at dc00 [size=8]
    Memory at d0000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at f7ec0000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
    Kernel driver in use: i915
```

Comment: added the output.

Comment: realised I got a bug during the upgrade with gdk-pixbuf, reinstalling fixed the chrome problem, but sublime-text bug remains. "sudo aptitude reinstall gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 gtk2-engines-pixbuf libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common"

Comment: Please file a bug on this issue: http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug

Comment: @abuhurayra After you have filled the bug, if you want to return to the previous behavior, check your `/var/log/dpkg.log` and reinstall any proposed package.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdk-pixbuf/+bug/1212433

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, all seems fixed now.

The problem with Chrome was because of an error in the upgrade

```
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme ...
(gtk-update-icon-cache-3.0:757): GdkPixbuf-WARNING **: Cannot open pixbuf loader module file '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders.cache': No such file or directory
This likely means that your installation is broken.
Try running the command
  gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders > /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders.cache
to make things work again for the time being.
```

Reinstalling the pixpuf packages and installing the last upgrade fixed the bug in Chrome

```
sudo aptitude reinstall gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 gtk2-engines-pixbuf libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common</pre>
```

For Sublime-text, the bug came from the soda theme that I installed a long time ago (it didn't like the last update...)
removing the theme from configuration fixed it :

**Sublime Text 2 > Preferences > Settings > User** I
removed **theme: Soda Light.sublime-theme**

Answer (score 0):

You could try to revert to a stable version of xorg and disable compositing. To do so, open your terminal window and run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

You should then be using the stable release of xorg.

To disable compositing, open the `Settings Manager` and select `Window Manager Tweaks`. Under `Compositor`, disable the `Enable display compositing` option